# Boundedness of average of function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

I need to compute a covariance function of a process, which yields the limit
$$I:=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{U\times U}dx\,dy\,f(x)\,f(y)\,|B^d(\varepsilon)|^{-1}\mathbb{1}\{||x-y||\leq\varepsilon\} \ ,$$
where $U$ is some domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $f\in L^2(U)$, and $|B^d(\varepsilon)|$ is the volume of the $d$-dimensional ball of radius $\varepsilon$.

If I could switch limit with integral, this would be
$$I = \int_Udx\,f(x)\ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\ |B^d(\varepsilon)|^{-1}\int_{||y-x||<\varepsilon}{dy\,f(y)}$$
and using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, this last limit of the average of $f$ around $x$ is $f(x)$, hence $I=||f||^2_{L^2}$.

Now, how can I use the Dominated or Monotone convergence theorem to justify that switch of limit and integral? I tried using the Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality, but I couldn't properly bound the average of $f(x)$.

Note: I checked [these Tao's lectures](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes3.pdf), and in the last inequality of Proposition 1.1 he has a bound that could work for me, if the norm that he calls $||\cdot||_{L^{1,\infty}}$ were actually the $L^\infty$ norm. What does he mean by $L^{1,\infty}$ there?

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, $L^{1,\infty}$ is a Lorentz space, and I don't think that inequality would work for the DCT or MCT here. Any other thoughts?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_{L^{1,\infty}}$ refers to the *Lorentz Spaces*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space

Comment: Ohh ok thanks. Then after looking at the definition I don't think it will be useful for me in order to properly bound the average of $f$ at $x$ and use the DCT or MCT.

Comment: What is $B^d$ here? Does it refer to the unit ball or is it related to Brownian motion? (Your post says covariance which is why I ask)

Comment: Yes, I just clarified it in the post.